# Search SQL Table and only Return columns with Text

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to search a table and only return rows and columns in which the search term is found. I’ve tried to do up a small diagram below to help out.

Below is an example table, with the term “Testing” what I want to search for:

[image]

I would like a query that could return something like this:

[image]

Perhaps something like

```
Select 'function to only select some columns'
FROM Example_Table
Where RowID = 'Row1'
```

If possible, i was hoping to do it with a simple Select Query rather than create some sort of function for it.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: There is no simple query to do this. You will have to use dynamic sql and it isn't going to be pretty. This is just not really how databases are supposed to work.

Comment: A select always returns a fixed number of columns, independent of current table data.

Comment: Why are columns 2 and 4 not in your desired results?

Comment: Thanks everyone, i knew it was going to be touch and go whether it could be done but was hopeful there would be an easy solution. The project i've inherited is pretty messy and thought this would be the easiest way to grab the data.
Columns 2 and 4 are not in the results as they do not contain the text needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve your problem:

```
DECLARE @rowid varchar(10) = 'Row1'
DECLARE @columns varchar(200) = ''

SELECT @columns += ','+[Col]
FROM Example_Table
UNPIVOT      
(Items FOR Col IN           
([col1], [col2], [col3]) ) AS unpvt  
WHERE rowID = @rowid

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = 
  'SELECT RowID' + @columns 
  + ' FROM Example_Table WHERE RowID = @id'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@id nvarchar(10)', @rowid
```

Comment: That is pretty much what i was after! thank you for that!
How would you change that to include a search term? For instance if i had another word in a column saying "1234" it picks that up in the query, but I only want to return columns with "testing" in it.